# "This field is required." DRF

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-registration

Began to deal with `DRF`. I want to authenticate users with `jwt token`. But nothing happens. I’ve come across the problem that when creating a user, I get: *{"user": {"email": ["This field is required."], "Username": ["This field is required."], "Password": ["This field is required."]}}.* Although all the fields are filled.

**models**

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        if username is None:
            raise TypeError('Users must have a username.')
​
        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Users must have an email address.')
​
        user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user
​
​
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bio = RichTextUploadingField(_('bio'), blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(_('city'), max_length=100, blank=True)
​
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
​
    objects = UserManager()
​
    @property
    def token(self):
        return self._generate_jwt_token()
​
    def _generate_jwt_token(self):
        dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=60)
​
        token = jwt.encode({
            'id': self.pk,
            'exp': int(dt.strftime('%s'))
        }, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')

        return token.decode('utf-8')
```

​
**serializers**

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        min_length=8,
        write_only=True
    )
    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)
​
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'token']

​
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

​
**view**

```
class RegistrationAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    renderer_classes = (UserJSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializer
​
    def post(self, request):
        print('request.data: \t\t', request.data)         #<QueryDict: {'{\n    "email": "sasasas@sasas.ssas",\n    "username": "sasasasas",\n    "password": "12345678"\n}': ['']}>
        print('request.data.get("user", {}): \t', request.data.get('user', {}))            #{}
        user = request.data.get('user', {})
​
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)     #Error
        serializer.save()
​
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Why are you passing in user as data? `self.serializer_class(data=user)` instead of  `data=request.data`?

Comment: I saw it here ... Thank you.
https://thinkster.io/tutorials/django-json-api/authentication

Comment: Also, DRF provides a `CreateAPIView` that you can use for create-only endpoints.
http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.generics/CreateAPIView.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't read the tutorial in detail, but it seems that for some reason the payload you post to the endpoint should be of a different shape than what DRF usually expects.

> There is one thing we need to fix though. Notice how the response from
>   the "Register" request has all of the user's information at the root
>   level. Our client expects this information to be namespaced under
>   "user." To do that, we'll need to create a custom DRF renderer.

So instead of posting this:

```
{ 
  "email": "user@example.com",
  "username": "user",
  "password": "hunter2"
}
```

You have to nest it all under the "user" key.

```
{
  "user": { 
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "username": "user",
    "password": "hunter2"
  }
}
```